# Database Design daily data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a question about database design, I'm wondering how do you go about saving daily user data.

For example I have a table called **Accounts**

structure is `accountID, accountName, DailyScore, WinRate`

how can I keep track of DailyScore and WinRate for each day. Do I keep creating tables named after a date or is there a better way.

Comment: Add a new column for the day, which can be of date or timestamp type.

Comment: Uhm, why don't you put in a date column within the structure?

Comment: even though I have many users, would that cause a problem?, it would look like this then? [day1,ID=5,name=test , score = 2, winrate = 6] [day2,ID=5, name.... and son on

Comment: It wouldn't, it would actually make querying a lot easier since you can filter by day/date.

Comment: would you recommend having each player with a table or have everything in a row, against thanks for your help

Comment: What is your first guess user189 on that one

Comment: Well, I am explicitly telling you to have a single table with all your players within it and all the player properties within every row.

Answer (score 1):

`Accounts` has info about each "account" -- account_id, name, etc.  This table is rather static -- you occasionally add a row, and sometimes change something.

`Scores` has new rows every day -- account_id, date, score, etc.  The `PRIMARY KEY` would have two columns: account_id and date.

Not knowing how winRate is calculated, it is unclear where, if anywhere, it should be stored.  Is it calculated from the scores??